how to notify a role or person in discord when the webhook sends form to channel
I have a script on a google form that sends answers fro specific questions to a discord channel.
What i cant get to work is for it to notify a specific role in discord that the message has been added to the channel.
I have put the role ID between a <@ and a > but the role or person does not show up on in the discord channel so they are not notified by being @.
function postFeedbackToDiscord() 
{


<@747564883133857792>

  // Load the form and it's responses
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var newResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1]; // Get the last (newest) response
  var itemResponses = newResponse.getItemResponses();
    

  // Get the question responses that you want to include in the Discord message
  // In this case, I want the first 3 question responses
  var q1 = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var q2 = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var q3 = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  var q4 = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  var q7 = itemResponses[22].getResponse();
  var q8 = itemResponses[23].getResponse();
  var q9 = itemResponses[24].getResponse();
  var q20 = itemResponses[25].getResponse();
  var q21 = itemResponses[26].getResponse();
  var q22 = itemResponses[27].getResponse();
  var q24 = itemResponses[29].getResponse();
  
  var fields = [

    {
      name: "__q1__",
      value: trainername.toString()
    },
    {
      name: "__q2__ ",
      value: trainerperm.toString()
    },
    {
    name: "__q3__",
    value: traineename.toString()
    },

    {
    name: "__q4__",
    value: traineeperm.toString()
    },

    {
    name: "__q7__",
    value: Citysmallarms.toString()
    },
    {
    name: "__q8__",
    value: junctiondelperro.toString()
    },
    {
    name: "__q9__",
    value: wheretoland.toString()
    },
    {
    name: "__q20__",
    value: whoflyec135.toString()
    },
    {
    name: "__q21__",
    value: howgoodfly.toString()
    },
    {
    name: "__q22__",
    value: passorfail.toString()
    },
    {
    name: "__q24__",
    value: feedtostudent.toString()
    }
  ]
 


  // Set the color to Red if the feedback is reporting an Issue / Bug
  // Otherwise, set it to green
  var statusColor = (passorfail.toString() == "Issue / Bug") ?  15605837 : 1879160

  // Construct the embeded message
  var embededMessage = {
    color: statusColor,
    fields: fields
  };

   // Construct the post request
  var url = "webhook addres here";
  var payload = JSON.stringify({embeds: [embededMessage]});
  var params = {
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  // Send the post request to the Discord webhook
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  
  // Log the response
  Logger.log(res.getContentText());
}

Please could someone help me with specifics to add to my script to get the @role or @name notified in my discord channel,
